# Vim remove windows characters (convert to unix file format)

Tags: vim

I copied a vimrc file from a windows box running gvim and tried using it on an OSX box.  Turns out there are a bunch of characters that my unix vim doesn't like in the file.  I assume they're Windows EOL characters or something - doesn't really matter.  Anyway, **Is there an easy way to remove them all at once, or convert the file to a unix friendly format?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, figured it out.  To convert to a nice unix format, just use `:set ff=unix` then `:w`.  See this [S/O answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/82743/752916)...

Comment: Or remove them with `:%s/<C-v><Enter>//`. Vim on Windows supports Unix EOL but Vim on Unix doesn't like Windows EOL. It's best to always use Unix EOL.